# "Service account authorization without OAuth", can we get file from Google Cloud Storage via this approach?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Per this documentation [Addendum: Service account authorization without OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth), it says

> If the API you want to call has a service definition published in the [Google APIs GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis), you can make authorized API calls using a JWT instead of an access token

I see [Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/storage/v1/storage_v1.yaml) published on that Github repository but I can not seem to be able to get a file on Google Cloud Storage with the approach in the documentation. According to JWT header and payload example show in step 3 of the documentation, I did the following adjustments

- Change `kid` from `abcdef1234567890` to my service account `private_key_id`
- Change `iss` and `sub` to my service account `client_email`
- Change `aud` to `https://storage.googleapis.com/`
- Change `iat` and `exp` to now and now + 1 hour

I use signed JWT as bearer token trying to get file from `http://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/path/file` but I keep getting this response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code><Message>Authentication required.</Message></Error>
```

Can we really use this approach with Google Cloud Storage? Am I doing anything wrong?

Note that I can access the file with oauth access_token when following [another approach described on the same page documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) but I prefer not to make a request to get access_token first before making a request to get the file.

Comment: Yes, you can use this approach. The important item is that the service account private key is used to sign requests verifying that you have the appropriate permissions. However, that method is dying out in Google Cloud. I recommend using OAuth Access Tokens instead of Signed JWTs. The extra call to Google to exchange the JWT for tokens is minor and only needs to be done once per hour. I am not sure but there may be overhead for Google to lookup the public key to verify your private key signature increasing latency.

Answer (score 2):

I drew the same conclusion as you from reading this documentation, but it doesn't work for me either on Google Cloud Storage.

It does work on some services like Google Cloud Pub/Sub.

I also confirmed that the Google Cloud SDK doesn't use the "Service account authorization without OAuth" method for GCS, but it does for Pub/Sub.

For example in the Node.js SDK, the variable determining whether or not to use this method is [`useSelfSignedJWT` in `google-auth-library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/b48254490768799e465a8fa4aae13296ddceea53/src/auth/jwtclient.ts#L126):

```js
const useSelfSignedJWT =
  (!this.hasUserScopes() && url) ||
  (this.useJWTAccessWithScope && this.hasAnyScopes());
```

A service like Pub/Sub that supports self-signed JWT [sets `useJWTAccessWithScope = true`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/ba333c2284b802cdd43df7568b553b2a90dba8d8/src/v1/publisher_client.ts#L139), but GCS [doesn't
set this variable](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/search?q=useJWTAccessWithScope).

That being said I forced the GCS SDK to use self-signed JWT and got it to work that way!

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')

const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: 'service-account-key.json'
})

storage.authClient.useJWTAccessWithScope = true

// Use client and watch how it doesn't call the OAuth2 endpoint,
// and requests are still successful.
```

The interesting thing to note is that the self-signed JWT that Google SDK generated is a bit different from what they document for [Service account authorization without OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth):

```json
{
  "iss": "service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
  "exp": 1234567890,
  "iat": 1234567890
}
```

Whereas their documentation says to use a `aud` field and doesn't mention scopes:

> ```json
> {
>   "iss": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
>   "sub": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
>   "aud": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/",
>   "iat": 1511900000,
>   "exp": 1511903600
> }
> ```

So you can set a `scope` field with a valid OAuth scope, e.g. [for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication). This did work for me on GCS, and it might work for other APIs that don't accept self-signed tokens with `aud`.

Comment: For what it's worth, a separate document from Google talks about the use of the `scope` claim in self-signed JWTs: https://google.aip.dev/auth/4111

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Val. This literally chewed up a day of our time. For anyone else, to upload files to a google storage bucket we had to replace the `aud` with a `scope` entry:

`"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"`